# Sub-query with count(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get the data that is failed that associate with `left(number,7)` from sub query `count(*)` data?

For example I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE outcome = 'Fail' AND left(number,7) = 
   (SELECT count(*) as total, left(number,7) as prefix  
   FROM table1 where outcome like '%Passed%' 
   group by prefix order by total desc limit 250)
```

This wont work because there are two fields in the sub-query.. so how to get around that?

Comment: You don't need the count(*) in the select list as you don't use it anyway. Using an `order by count(*)` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` instead of subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.total, ... 
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT count(*) as total, left(number,7) as prefix  
    FROM table1 
    where outcome like '%Passed%' AND outcome = 'Fail'
    group by prefix 
    order by total desc limit 250
) AS t2 ON t2.prefix = left(t1.number,7)
```

Comment: Good catch. That also avoids a possible "sub-query returns more than one row" error.

Comment: `where outcome like '%Passed%' AND outcome = 'Fail'` seem to be wrong. That is not how I do it from my question

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back - then put it in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
   table1 a 
 INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
      count(*) as total, 
      left(number,7) as prefix  
   FROM 
      table1 
   where 
      outcome like '%Passed%' 
   group by 
      prefix 
   order by 
      total desc limit 250)b
 ON 
   a.outcome = 'Fail' AND 
   left(number,7) = b.prefix
```